# NLog in .NET Core doesn't archive the log file

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I have NLog which is logging into my log file, but it doesn't archive the log file, I still see the logs from yesterday in the log file they are not archived and I see no new files created for archives. Below is the configuration code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="C:\temp\EMCS\ItemAPI\ItemAPI-internal-nlog.txt">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <variable name="logDirectory" value="C:\temp\EMP\ITEM"/>
  <targets>
      <!-- write logs to file  -->
       <target xsi:type="File"
       name="file"
       archiveEvery="Day"
       archiveFileName = "ItemAPI-{########}.log"
       archiveNumbering = "Date"
       archiveDateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"
       maxArchiveFiles = "4"
       fileName="${logDirectory}\ItemAPI.log"
       layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${aspnet-user-identity}|${machinename}|${processname}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Am I missing anything in file log configuration ? why I don't see archives getting created and my file log no getting clean up when I run the solution.

Comment: When you override the directory for `fileName`, then you should also do it for `archiveFileName`. Ex. `archiveFileName = "${logDirectory}\ItemAPI-{########}.log"`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
    <add assembly="NLog.Appsettings.Standard"/>
  </extensions>

  <variable name="logDirectory" value="C:\temp\EMCS\Item\ItemAPI"/>
  <variable name="archiveDirectory" value="C:\temp\EMCS\Item\archive"/>

  <targets>

    <target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="all" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">

      <!-- write logs to database  -->
      <target name="database" xsi:type="Database"
             connectionString="${appsettings:name=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
             commandText="INSERT INTO [LOGS](EventId,SeverityValue,Timestamp,MachineName,AppDomainName,ProcessId,ProcessName,ThreadId,ThreadName,[User],MessageText,FormattedMessageText) 
           VALUES (@eventId,@severityValue,@timestamp,@machineName,@appDomainName,@processId,@processName,@threadId,@threadName,@user,@messageText,@formattedMessageText)">

        <parameter name="@eventId" layout="${sequenceid}" />
        <parameter name="@severityValue" layout="${uppercase:${level}}" />
        <parameter name="@timestamp" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="@machineName" layout="${machinename}" />
        <parameter name="@appDomainName" layout="${appdomain}" />
        <parameter name="@processId" layout="${processid}" />
        <parameter name="@processName" layout="${processname}" />
        <parameter name="@threadId" layout="${threadid}" />
        <parameter name="@threadName" layout="${threadname}" />
        <parameter name="@user" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
        <parameter name="@messageText" layout="${message}" />
        <parameter name="@formattedMessageText" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${aspnet-user-identity}|${machinename}|${processname}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring} ${stacktrace}" />
      </target>

      <!-- write logs to file  -->
      <target xsi:type="File"
             name="file"
             fileName="${logDirectory}.log"
             layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${aspnet-user-identity}|${machinename}|${processname}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}"
             keepFileOpen ="false"
             concurrentWrites ="true"
             archiveNumbering="DateAndSequence"
             archiveDateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
             archiveAboveSize="10000000"
             archiveFileName="${archiveDirectory}\ItemAPI.{#}.log"
             maxArchiveFiles="10"/>

    </target>
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="all" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```